# Convert SQL DateTime to Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, datetime

I have a a field in my database saving a date as DateTime. I wish to change its format to dd-MM-yyyy. Here is my present Java/JSP code but it is returning an exception:

```
DateFormat formatter ;
Date date;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
date = (Date) formatter.parse(rs.getString("play_date")); //rs -> ResultSet
//print date...
```

What is the best way to be able to get the date?

Comment: mysql's date/time format is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, not dd-MMM-yy.

Comment: Use the JodaTime library instead of the crappy built-in date/time functions of Java and you won't have any trouble.

Comment: Do you want to just print it on dd-MM-yyyy format or change the format it is stored in the database?

Comment: Just did what @Jon Skeet, Webuser and Anubhava and it worked correctly. How can I change how the date is formatted, like show the time etc.?

Comment: To display time as well use a slightly different SimpleDateFormat like: `DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: When I did that it still displayed time like "19-01-12 00:00:00" :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of: `rs.getString("play_date")` you should do:

```
rs.getDate("play_date")
```

since your column `play_date` is of DATE_TIME in your database. There is no need to do any parsing either. You can directly display the time in `dd-MM-yyyy` format using [DateFormat#format(date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the column time is `DATETIME` and your SQL retrieves that column's values without explicitly converting them to a string, you can use the `getDate(String)` method of ResultSet.

```
date = rs.getDate("play_date");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database has the value as a date/time field, you shouldn't be performing any string conversions at all. Just use [`ResultSet.getDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `getString` - you should almost *always* avoid unnecessary transformations; they're a recipe for a disaster.

After all, the data doesn't *inherently* have a single textual representation - why would you want to make your code fragile in the face of (say) database configuration changes, when you can get the data in its natural representation?

The same is true when you *provide* data to the database (either as updates/inserts or query parameters) - use parameter values to avoid having to convert values into strings (and also to avoid SQL injection for values which are already strings).

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake with

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

It should probably be

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
```

With only 2 M's.